# Subrelatório com iReport em Java - The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null

Tags: java, lista, ireport

Olá!

Estou estudando iReport Design e comecei utilizando Connection no meu fillReport. Até aí, estava tudo bem. O problema é que, agora, eu passei a usar Collection, por meio dos comandos:

```
List<Vendas> vendas = new VendasDAO().getVendasPorPeriodo(
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("20180101"),
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("20180131")
        );

JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(vendas);
```

Dessa forma, quando eu tento executar, me aparece o seguinte erro:

> ADVERTÊNCIA: The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null.